# css to link tag in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a link tag of rails like below

```
<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

I want to increase the `font size` of the `New Product` and apply some CSS property to it.

Can I do that in the rails tag itself?

Comment: Yes, you can as said in the above link. But I will still use a class instead of inline styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path, {style: 'font-size: 2em;  color: black' } %>
```

But a nicer solution would be, to add a class to the link, and than style the class in a separate css-file.

```
<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path, class: 'myclass'  %>
```

CSS-File:

```
.myclass {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: `<%= link_to 'New Expense', new_expense_path {style: 'font-size: 2em;  color: black' } %>
`

I get syntax error for some reason 

 syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'

Comment: okay, I was missing the comma. my bad 
And yes I am using the secodn method